# Deserialize Json and store part of it into list of objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

How can I deserialize this Json and hold all the **Datafield** and **HeaderText** in List of SampleClass

```
 public class SampleClass
{
    public string Datafield { get; set; }
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
}

{
    "SummaryResults": {
      "ControlType": "Table",
      "ColumnDefinitions": [
        {
          "Datafield": "SourceSystem",
          "HeaderText": "Source System"
        },
        {
          "Datafield": "ChildHoldType",
          "HeaderText": "Child Hold Type"
        },
        {
          "Datafield": "CompanyNumber",
          "HeaderText": "Company Number"
        },
        {
          "Datafield": "Queue",
          "HeaderText": "Queue"
        },
        {
          "Datafield": "Country",
          "HeaderText": "Country"
        },
        {
          "HeaderText": "Count",
          "ControlDefinition": {
            "ControlType": "Hyperlink",
            "DisplayText": "@{Count}",
            "URL" :  ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? I hope you know at least the basics of serialization, in particular of JSON. So show where *exactly* you have difficulties by providing your code.

Comment: You cannot. The last array entry does not fit in SampleClass.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to do using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API:

```
List<SampleClass> list = JToken.Parse(json)
    .SelectToken("SummaryResults.ColumnDefinitions")
    .Children<JObject>()
    .Select(jo => jo.ToObject<SampleClass>())
    .ToList();
```

However, note the last item in the JSON array does not have a `Datafield` so it will be null in the resulting list.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9dl2wP

Comment: Thanks for the solution